# When will If else break with all conditions javascript

Tags: javascript, performance

When will else condition executed ?? is there any possibility of i value which will not satisfy any **if , else if** condition and reach else block in javascript.

```
random = Math.random();
i=0; //0,0.1,0.001
console.log(random);
if(random < i) {
   console.log("<");
} else if(random > i) {
   console.log(">");
} else if(random == i) {
   console.log("=");
}else{
   console.log("nothing");
}
```

Comment: mathematically speaking, it shouldn't be hit.

Comment: @t.niese in general, yes, but in this case no, since `i` and `random` have both been assigned proper numeric values

Comment: @t.niese i value is assigned

Comment: @user1837779 if you assign `i` as result of a calculation, then it might be `NaN`. And you could for sure set it to `NaN` directly `i=NaN;`

Answer (score 1):

Else will never be reached. The Result of `Math.random()` is between 0 and 1 (see [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp))

Comment: 0 inclusive, and 1 _exclusive_.  And please refer people to MDN, not w3fools - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Comment: That's wrong, comparing `NaN` with anything will never return true; NaN will reach the else-block.